# Powershell Get-Date not formatting properly

Tags: powershell, datetime, culture

I have a date I am reading from somewhere so I am retrieving as a string value. My Culture is de-DE but need the time to have the AM/PM for when the script runs in en-US:

```
$date = 10.04.2018 14:40:20
$NewDate = Get-Date -Date $date -Format "dd MMM yyyy h:mm:ss tt"
```

What I want is $NewDate to be 10 Apr 2018 2:40:20 PM but am only able to get 10 Apr 2018 2:40:20. In english the tt translates to an AM/PM just fine, but how do I get it here?

Comment: Have you run this on an en_US system? What was the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to rely on a certain date string, no matter where and with what culture information your script is run, you have to define a fixed culture info for your output:

```bsh
$date = '10.04.2018 14:40:20'
$culture = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CreateSpecificCulture('en-US')
(Get-Date $date).ToString('dd MMM yyyy h:mm:ss tt', $culture)
```

Output:

```
10 Apr 2018 2:40:20 PM
```

The output will always be the same, even on your 'de-DE' machine. You can read more about date formatting in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61222106/11942268).

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/08/25/use-culture-information-in-powershell-to-format-dates/), and adapt this code to achieve what you want.

```
$cultures = "en-US","en-GB","fr-CA","fr-FR","ms-MY","zh-HK", "de-DE"

foreach ($c in $cultures)

{

 $culture = New-Object system.globalization.cultureinfo($c)

 $date = get-date -format ($culture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern)

 New-Object psobject -Property @{"name"=$culture.displayname; "date"=$date}

}
```

Also be sure to look at the various properties of `$culture.DateTimeFormat`.

Comment: This might work, or some of those code. I think I will dynamically get the current culture but I just need it in that format which is a custom format

Answer (score 0):

The $date variable is not a datetime type. Actually, this assignment will not run. I assume you meant to make it a string. Use `ParseExact()` to convert it to a date.

```
$date = [datetime]::ParseExact('10.04.2018 14:40:20','M.d.yyyy H:m:s', $null)
$NewDate = Get-Date -Date $date -Format "dd MMM yyyy h:mm:ss tt"
```

Comment: Assuming the OP just forgot quotes on `$date = '10.04.2018 14:40:20'`, then their code does run because that string will be converted to DateTime.  I suspect the issue is with the de-DE culture and interop there.

Comment: my issue is really that in the US April 10 would be 4/10/2018 and in Germany it would be 10/4/2018. I can't use parseExact because I don't know the exact format that it will be in at all times.

Comment: If you do not know the incoming data, I do not know what can be done. Selecting a culture, as @KoryGill suggested, will still need to be done on the basis of the incoming data format. Will the incoming data be in en_US format when the program is run on a US machine and in de_DE format when run on a German machine?