# Date Time format displays differently in ISE and Windows Forms

Tags: powershell, date, time, format

When I run `Get-Date` in ISE, I get `Wednesday, 15 April 2020 12:38:03 PM` which I want.

However, if I run the same command in Windows Forms, I get `04/15/2020 12:38:03` in a different format.

I run them from the same computer so it must be the same cultural/region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1. Customizing your date using `-Format` or `-UFormat`

You can use the `-Format` or the `-UFormat` paramater to enforce a certain layout of your date:

```
Get-Date -Format "dddd, d MMMM yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"
Get-Date -UFormat "%A, %e %B %Y %r"
```

Both will display your desired date format, as long as you are using `en-US` culture information:

> `Wednesday, 15 April 2020 08:09:24 AM`

Learn more about:

- [.NET format specifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?view=netframework-4.8)
- [UFormat specifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-7#notes)

### 2. Customizing your date with different culture information

If you want to display the date in a different language, you can also enforce a certain culture information. Keep in mind that the `-Format` parameter is just a wrapper for the `ToString()` method. So you can also use the following line to display your date as desired:

```
(Get-Date).ToString('dddd, d MMMM yyyy hh:mm:ss tt')
```

Fortunately, there exist different overloads of that `ToString()` method. There is also one, that takes culture information as a second parameter. So in conclusion you can pass different culture info to your `ToString()` method to get results in different languages:

```
$culture = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CreateSpecificCulture('en-US')
(Get-Date).ToString('dddd, d MMMM yyyy hh:mm:ss tt', $culture)
```

will display:

> `Wednesday, 15 April 2020 08:09:24 AM`

and at the same time

```
$culture = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CreateSpecificCulture('de-DE')
(Get-Date).ToString('dddd, d MMMM yyyy hh:mm:ss tt', $culture)
```

will display:

> `Mittwoch, 15 April 2020 08:09:24`

### 3. Customizing your date with predefined culture specific patterns

In `$culture.DateTimeFormat` you can also find already prepared culture specific patterns to format your date and you can use them instead of writing them on your own:

```
$culture = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CreateSpecificCulture('en-US')
(Get-Date).ToString($culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern, $culture)
```

will display:

> `4/15/2020`

and at the same time

```
$culture = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CreateSpecificCulture('de-DE')
(Get-Date).ToString($culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern, $culture)
```

will display:

> `15.04.2020`

Btw: A similar pattern to yours, specified in your question, would be:

```
$culture = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CreateSpecificCulture('en-US')
(Get-Date).ToString($culture.DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern, $culture)
```

> `Wednesday, April 15, 2020 8:09:24 AM`