# Date field is not giving milliseconds while executing SQL script in PowerShell

Tags: sql, powershell, datetime, powershell-2.0

I wrote a script to execute SQL query and send email to user with SQL results. 
Database column has Date field in format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss:mi` but the SQL result in power shell giving me the format of `YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss`. The result is not consisting of `Milliseconds` and date is in different format. If I have to get milliseconds also in the result date, how should I format??

```
param (
     [Parameter(mandatory = "true")]
     [string]$sqlserver,
     [Parameter(mandatory = "true")]
     [string]$sqlusername,
     [Parameter(mandatory = "true")]
     [string]$sqlpassword,
     [Parameter(mandatory = "true")]
     [string]$databasename
)
$query = "select * from dbo.UserDetails where createdate > '2020-04-13' order by createdate"
$Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
$Connection.ConnectionString = "server='$Server';database='$databasename'; User ID = 'sqlusername' password= '$sqlpassword'"
$Connection.Open()
$Command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
$Command.Connection = $Connection
$Command.CommandText = $query
$DataAdapter = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $Command
$Dataset = new-object System.Data.Dataset
$DataAdapter.Fill($Dataset)
$Connection.Close()
$noOfRows = $Dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count
$UserCreateDate = $Dataset.Tables[0].Rows[$noOfRows - 1].ItemArray[6]
Write-Host ("The Latest User created " + $UserCreateDate)
```

**Output:**
4/14/2020 12:25:03

Value in DB: **2020-04-14 12:25:03.6028312**

Comment: @Krishna - just FYI ... the `mi` formatting code you used is not valid for dotnet - and thus not valid for powershell. here are the format strings that are valid for making custom datetime strings ... >>> Custom date and time format strings | Microsoft Docs — https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings <<< ///// also, you use `hh` but lack the `AM/PM` indicator. you likely should use `HH` to get the 24 hour time format. [*grin*]

Comment: @Krishna If you want to read more about date formatting in PS, I recommend reading [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61222106/11942268).

Answer (score 1):

Powershell is converting your SQL output into a [`DateTime`-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netcore-3.1). The default output format is determined by your set culture (try `(Get-Culture).datetimeformat` for more informations about your settings).

There are multiple ways to get the desired output:

1. Format the Output to a string using the [`.ToString`-Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netcore-3.1):

```
$UserCreateDate = ($Dataset.Tables[0].Rows[$noOfRows - 1].ItemArray[6]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")
```

2. Using [`Get-Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-7) and the `-Format` parameter:

```
$UserCreateDate = Get-Date ($Dataset.Tables[0].Rows[$noOfRows - 1].ItemArray[6]) -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"
```

Please keep in mind that both options will convert the output into a string and won't keep the DateTime-Object.

Both solutions format the datetime with a given format-string. [@Lee_Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) was so nice to point out the possible formats from the documentation here: [Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: the second point has worked for me. Regarding the first point, Date I'm pulling from the DB is already is a string. Will the Tostring conversion work on String?

Comment: @Krishna No, it won't as the `ToString()` method with .NET format specifiers is an overload of the `ToString()` method of a `datetime` object and not in general.