# Formatting a UTC time

Tags: powershell, datetime, datetime-format

I am looking to get the current UTC time, add 2 hours to it, then format both in the UTC format, so I can store that data in an XML file. Ultimate goal is then to get current UTC time on another machine, that could be in another time zone, and compare to the incremented time. So I can conditionally do stuff if two hours hasn't passed.

What I have is this

```
$now = Get-Date
$enqueued = $now.ToUniversalTime().ToString('u')
$expires = $now.Addhours(2).ToUniversalTime().ToString('u')

Write-Host "Q: $enqueued"
Write-Host "E: $expires"
```

`$enqueued` is formatted correctly, but `$expires` is not. I get

```
Q: 2020-06-02 18:41:58Z
E: 06/02/2020 22:41:58
```

And I expect

```
Q: 2020-06-02 18:41:58Z
E: 2020-06-02 20:41:58Z
```

I tried swapping `.Addhours(2)` & `.ToUniversalTime()` but it still doesn't format at all.

Interestingly

```
$now = (Get-Date).Addhours(2).ToUniversalTime().ToString('u')
$now
```

works right. So it's not the adding of hours alone. It's more like, once it's a variable the ability to add hours AND format is lost. Does that make any sense?

I also tried moving the UTC part to the $now assignment, since it was duplicated before.

```
$now = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()
$enqueued = $now.ToString('u')
$expires = $now.Addhours(2).ToString('u')

Write-Host "Q: $enqueued"
Write-Host "E: $expires"
```

Same results, `$expires` won't format.

Comment: So proper format for you is `MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:SS`, try checking out the `-format` switch of `get-date`. It may help you.

Comment: This will have varying results depending on the system. For me, the `$now = Get-Date
$enqueued = $now.ToUniversalTime().ToString('u')
$expires = $now.Addhours(2).ToUniversalTime().ToString('u')` worked properly and as intended.

Comment: Oh, dear gawd. I installed PS 5.1 on my Windows 7 test VM, and everything worked right. Then I rolled the VM back to a snapshot with PS5.0. And it works there too now. SO I am starting to think it just needed a reboot. Sometimes I forget Windows needs rebooted every 2 minutes or so, to keep things working right. :)

Comment: @Gordon If you want to read more about date formatting, you may want to check my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61222106/11942268).