# Powershel convert from milliseconds to time format

Tags: powershell, datetime, datetime-format

I have this code to format my result in time format.

```
  [TimeSpan[]]$outItems = foreach ($eachtimer in $DurationColl){
  if ($eachtimer.Contains('M')){
  Convert-TimeString -Time  $eachtimer -Format 'm\Ms\.fff\S'}
  else{
  Convert-TimeString -Time $eachtimer -Format "h\:mm\:ss"} 
  }
  ($outItems | Measure-Object -Property TotalSeconds -Sum).Sum
  $ts =  [timespan]::fromseconds($outItems)
  ("{0:hh\:mm\:ss\,fff}" -f $ts)
```

This is the $outItems value
14738.631

> ```
> Cannot convert argument "value", with value: "System.TimeSpan[]", for "FromSeconds" to type "System.Double": "Cannot convert the 
> "System.TimeSpan[]" value of type "System.TimeSpan[]" to type "System.Double"."
> At line:3 char:4
> +    $ts =  [timespan]::fromseconds($outItems)
> +    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
> ```

This is the output that I get, but with the message above:

```
00:02:37.5260000
```

And I need to get something like this (hh:mm:ss.fff):

```
02:37.526
```

Can you please give me some help to understand what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: why do you expect the `[timespan]::FromSeconds()` call to accept an array?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61222106/11942268) you can find some additional info on datetime formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How 'bout this?  You were seeing the Sum property, but not capturing it.

```
$milliseconds=  ($outItems | Measure-Object -Property TotalSeconds -Sum).Sum
$ts =  [timespan]::fromseconds($milliseconds)
("{0:hh\:mm\:ss\,fff}" -f $ts)
```